# Ingress on one node can use pod on other node as backend?

Tags: kubernetes

Setting up a K8S cluster (RKE) on Hetzner, having 3 Ubuntu 22 worker nodes, using the Hetzner LoadBalancer.

So I tried to run the Google "hello" app and create service and Ingress.

Problem: it only works 1/3 of the time.

Can ingress running on node 1 not use a pod running on node 2 as backend? This would make the Hetzner load balancer unusable for this use case I suppose?

Comment: if your kubernetes cluster has a working SDN, then ingress pods can reach other pods on all your other nodes, given there's no networkpolicy denying this. How is your ingress exposed outside of SDN? If you have 3 nodes and only 1/3 of requests working: is it possible you have one ingress pod, running with `hostNetwork`? this would explain the two other nodes not responding. Or maybe some NodePort Service with externalTrafficPolicy to Local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change the network to flannel, then it worked.